# Vertically line up inline elements - align image on same line as text

Tags: html, css

Having trouble vertically lining up inline elements - I want the email image to line up with text on the same line and without causing adverse effects on the flow of sibling elements:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8C8C/)

**HTML:**

```
<p><span class="purple">phone:</span> 123.123.1234</p>
<p><span class="green">email:</span> <img src="http://www.illuminart.com/tests/img/email.png" alt="" style="width:172px; height:13px" /></p>
<p><span class="purple">phone:</span> 123.123.1234</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
p {    
    line-height: 15px;
}
span {}
img {}
```

**Update:**  setting the img to vertical-align:middle and changing the line-height from 'px' to 'em' seemed to work better.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
p {    
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
span {}
img { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this:http://jsfiddle.net/c8C8C/1/. do you want this?

I just only add **vertical-align:middle** in your img tag style attribute.

Comment: it is not quite what I am looking for, but thank you. maybe I can make it work.

Comment: vertical-align:middle pushes the 3rd paragraph down a couple of pixels. I tried adjusting margin or padding to fix that, without any luck.

Comment: your solution worked after I updated my line-height from 'px' to 'em'.

Comment: @BumbleB2na: I didn't see any difference, but the image was align to text. Can please provide more info what you want? So a more knowledgeable member help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @BumbleB2na: Great to hear dear, Please provide jsfiddle link in a new answer and accept it so this question becomes completed.

Answer (score 0):

## Vertically align emoji with text

**vertical-align** didn't work for me.

#### What worked for me was:

```
<h3 class="title"><span class="emoji"> </span> Some text here</h3>
```

- In HTML: having the emoji wrapped in a span
- in CSS:

  ```
    // on parent (i.e h3 or p)
    display: inline-flex 

    // on emoji wrapper span
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: -10px; // adjust this
  ```

You probably have to adjust *margin-top* value based on your font, line-height etc.

Hope it helps.

```css
.list-title {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.emoji {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: -10px; // adjust margin-top to your needs
}
```

```html
<h3 class="list-title"><span class="emoji"> </span> Some text here</h3>
<br>
<p class="list-title"><span class="emoji"> </span> Some text here</p>
```